# What is really being imported in Haskell

Tags: haskell, import

Perhaps it's a bit silly question, but I'm used to scripting languges, where the question never occurs, as there's no compilation at all. The question is: what is really imported to a Haskell executable: are whole imported libs incorporated or does it rather include in the executable only the code that is really necessary to run the program?

Suppose I have something like that:

```
import qualified Data.Set as Set

mySet = Set.fromList [1..5]

main = print $ Set.filter (\x -> x `mod` 2 == 0) mySet
```

Is whole `Data.Set` module included to the executable? Or does it rather include only `Set` definition and `fromList` and `filter` functions? Does it make any difference if I write:

```
import qualified Data.Set as Set (Set, fromList, filter)
```

At least executable size does not seem affected with the change...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A library module is linked as a whole unless it has been compiled with the GHC `-split-objs` option.  However this makes compilation slower, so it is not the default.  From [GHC documentation](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/options-phases.html#idp12295360):

> However, assembling all the sections separately is expensive, so this is slower than compiling normally. We use this feature for building GHC's libraries (warning: don't use it unless you know what you're doing!).

Answer (score 3):

By using `import` you just bring some definitions into scope.

It is the linker's job to call the functions from the library. The library is still the same, your code only contains calls to it.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but when you link statically, the library code is included in your executable so that your program can run without the library present in the system. That's the situation I am asking about.

Comment: You always get the full library.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the entire library will be included. But as you correctly pointed out some parts of the library will not be called either directly or indirectly. I believe, The code optimization stage of the compiler will remove those parts of the code which are not called. This should result in the final executable containing only those parts which are absolutely necessary.

Comment: But libraries are linked after the compilation so how GHC could possibly remove the code that's not there yet?

Comment: @Sventimir: when compiling, GHC produces interface files, which contain (among other things) definitions for values that are candidates for inlining.  Interface files must be available for every module that is imported during compilation, so it's possible to call functions from external packages at the source code level, but have those calls be entirely optimized out so that nothing from external libs/object files remains.  I think ghc will still link them in however, maybe `ld` doesn't include unused libs but I wouldn't count on it.